# Tomcat too many open files error (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: java, rest, ubuntu, tomcat

I have deployed my Java Rest Application in tomcat (ubuntu 18.04). Everything seems fine until this error shows :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/webapps/botiv1/WEB-INF/lib/javax.inject-2.5.0-b42.jar (Too many open files)
    java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:345)
    java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:259)
    java.base/java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:214)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.<init>(ZipFile.java:1263)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1229)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:727)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:845)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:245)
    java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:175)
    java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:341)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor7.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.JreCompat.jarFileNewInstance(JreCompat.java:149)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.openJarFile(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:307)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.getArchiveEntry(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:97)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractArchiveResourceSet.getResource(AbstractArchiveResourceSet.java:256)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResourceInternal(StandardRoot.java:281)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:62)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
    org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2260)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:834)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1297)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:422)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:285)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
    org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
    org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:703)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:416)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:370)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:389)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:342)
    org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:229)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    com.ritech.model.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:59)
```

I have set the limits to 65000, but this error still shows up after a couple of hours.

/etc/security/limits.conf file

*soft     nproc          65535

*hard     nproc          65535

*soft     nofile         65535

*hard     nofile         65535
root soft     nproc          65535

root hard     nproc          65535

root soft     nofile         65535

root hard     nofile         65535

webuser hard nofile 64000

Note: This is not a database connections leak, because i have tracked the opened/active connecions, and there are not more than 4 active connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Tomcat version. Version 9.0.13 would show "Too many open files" error, even when the total amount of opened files was around 5000 out of 100000 (limit). I updated the version to 9.0.14 and everything seems fine now.

Answer (score 2):

I assume tomcat service  is running under tomcat user.
check open files with command `lsof -u tomcat | wc -l`
check maximum number of file handles for the entire system with command: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`

check the current usage of file handles with command: `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`

to make the change permanent, add or change the following line in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`. This file is used during the boot process.
`echo "fs.file-max=65536" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` (values are valid after reboot)

run command `ulimit -a` and check number of open files( -n) and max user processes (-u)
increase the values if necessary.

```
e.g. : in /etc/security/limits.conf file 
tomcat              hard    nofile          102400
tomcat              soft    nofile          102400
```

run command: systemctl status tomcat
get `tomcat pid`and

check cat /proc/'tomcat pid'/limits, if limits are still at default values add below lines  to /etc/init.d/tomcat file.

ulimit -Hn 16384

ulimit -Sn 16384

after changing /etc/init.d/tomcat file restart tomcat service toapply changes.

Comment: I would use lsof to identify if there is a file which is open many times (opened again and again by Java code but never closed).

Comment: The server gave this error again.
 The lsof -u tomcat | wc -l command gives : 4128
  cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max : 100000
  cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr :
  5344 0 100000

The number of opened files is way below the limit.

Comment: The problem was with tomcat version (9.0.13). I updated to 9.0.14 , this error is not showing anymore.